# Republishing a Content Type

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, publishing

I created a content type with 3 fields and added it to 12 sites across the tenant. I then add a 4th column to the Content Type Gallery (Modern) and click republish. Shouldn't this new column propagate to all lists inheriting from the Hub Content Type? The only way to get the new column to show at the List level is to remove and re-add the Content Type but I don't want to do that to 12 sites because in a month it could be 50 sites.

What am I missing with this Content Type Rebuplishing feature? Should I use Site Content Types instead?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.You should click update sites and list option.

[image]

2.After applying it to libraries or lists if further changes are made to the enterprise content type and republished, the latest changes will be available 45 minutes to 1 hour after the republish action. You can also choose to update the content type to pull in the latest changes immediately, either programmatically or manually from the site-level content type gallery.

Referecne: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-s-changed-in-content-type-publishing-609399c7-5c42-4e25-aff0-b59d4aa1867f

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.